Why does constrained template function declaration with template parameter pack not compile when constraint has extra template parameter before pack?
I tried to write a generalized version of std::same_as that needs to work with any positive number of type arguments.
I wrote the following concept, keeping the first template parameter separate from the other template parameters because I needed to compare it against all the others:
template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
concept all_same_v1 = (... && std::same_as<T1, Ts>);

However, when using the concept above, the code below does not compile on GCC and Clang, but does compile on MSVC (godbolt link):
template <typename... Ts> requires all_same_v1<Ts...>
void f(Ts&&... ts);

The error on GCC is:
<source>:6:36: error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter 'T1' of concept 'template<class T1, class ... Ts> concept all_same_v1'
    6 | template <typename... Ts> requires all_same_v1<Ts...>
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:3:11: note: declared here
    3 | template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
      |           ^~~~~~~~

In contrast, the following O(N²) implementation works:
template <typename T, typename... Others>
concept same_with_others = (... && std::same_as<T, Others>);

template <typename... Types>
concept all_same_v2 = (... && same_with_others<Types, Types...>);

template <typename... Ts> requires all_same_v2<Ts...>
void f(Ts&&... ts);

Why is this so?

I suspect that it is related to P2963 and might be related to this question due to the fact that MSVC accepts it but both GCC and Clang refuses it.  However, this code here has nothing to do with concept subsumption.
